# Webpack file-loader adjust public path

Tags: webpack, webpack-file-loader, webpack-5

I have the following for my images folder:

```
module.exports = {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/,
        include: config.paths.images, // this is: path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets/images')
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            name: '[path][name].[ext]',
            publicPath: '../',
        }
    };
```

And this is what outputs for my css: `background-image: url(../images/assets/images/doctor-results/g-map-location.png);`

What I need is for the path to be: `background-image: url(../images/doctor-results/g-map-location.png);`

Essentially removing the first 2 directories from the path, while remaining relative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `split` and `splice` instead of adding another library.

```
{    
    options: {
        name: config.outputs.image.filename,
        publicPath: (url) => {
            const pathArray = url.split('/');
            pathArray.splice(0, 2);
            const path = pathArray.join('/');
            return `../${path}`;
        },
        emitFile: false
    }
}
```